# SqlAlchemy (Postgres + Flask ) : How to sum multiple columns?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a class `Score` with a column `item_id` and several fields having different scores types(score1, score2, score3...)all having integer values.

I need to write a query that takes the list of scores types and returns a list with objects having `itemid` and sum of the scores of all score types mentioned in the list alongside. I'm trying to do this using hybrid method but confused about how to write the query.

**model.py**

```
class Score(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'scores'

    item_id                     = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    score1                      = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score2                      = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score3                      = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score4                      = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_method
    def total_score(self, fields):
        ts = 0
        for field in fields : 
            ts = ts + self[field]
        return ts
```

**controller.py**

```
app.route('/scores', methods=['POST'])
def scores():
    fields = ['score1', 'score2']
    scores = Score.query.all().order_by('total_score')
```

Obviously this does not work. Could you please help me write the query, much thanks!

This is how I need to have the final output :

```
[{'item_id' : 'x1', 'total_score' : y1},{'item_id' : 'x2', 'total_score' : y2},{'item_id' : 'x3', 'total_score' : y3}, ...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid.hybrid_method.expression) for `hybrid_method`

```
class Score(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'scores'
    item_id  = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    score1 = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score2 = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score3 = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    score4 = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)

    @hybrid_method
    def total_score(self, fields):
        return sum(getattr(self, field) for field in fields)

    @total_score.expression
    def total_score(cls, fields):
        return sum(getattr(cls, field) for field in fields)


fields = ['score1', 'score2']
scores = db.session.query(Score.item_id, Score.total_score(fields).label('total_score')).order_by('total_score')
final_output = [score._asdict() for score in scores]
```

Comment: Isn't the explicit expression actually unnecessary in this particular case? In other words since the instance and class methods are identical, SQLA can implicitly use the "instance" method as the class (expression) method as well.

Comment: Isn't `@total_score.expression` supposed to define an equivalent query expression? https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#hybrid-distinct-expression