# Using sqlalchemy python query sum 2 column in table

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm newbie using python3
I have table wallets:

```
ID name score1 score2
 1 name1    10     11
 2 name2     1      2
 3 name3     5      6
```

How I query with result:

```
total_score = score1 + score 2

ID name total_score
 1 name1         21
 2 name2          3
 3 name3         11
```

Then i try to add hybrid_method to Wallet model:

```
@hybrid_method
def total_score(self, fields):
    return sum(getattr(self, field) for field in fields)

@total_score.expression
def total_score(cls, fields):
    return sum(getattr(cls, field) for field in fields)
```

AND :

```
wallets = Wallet.total_score(['socre1', 'score2']).label('total_score')
```

but nothing give at wallets variable.
Im using code in: [SqlAlchemy (Postgres + Flask ) : How to sum multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684242/sqlalchemy-postgres-flask-how-to-sum-multiple-columns)

Comment: Im using ORM, it's basic model , i want to sum 2 column bro

Comment: i trying to add hybrid_method to Wallet Model like code:
`@hybrid_method
    def total_score(self, fields):
        return sum(getattr(self, field) for field in fields)

    @total_score.expression
    def total_score(cls, fields):
        return sum(getattr(cls, field) for field in fields)
`

then using: `Wallet.total_score(['score1', 'score2']).label('total_score')`
but not working

Comment: im try to using code in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35684242/sqlalchemy-postgres-flask-how-to-sum-multiple-columns

Comment: Okay bro, ty for that

Comment: `wallets` is a column expression. Have you passed it to `session.query()` or such?

Comment: Yeah bro, got it, my real match is add condition when search

Comment: why you don't use `hybrid property`? and what is your purpose?
you want to filter users with the sum of score of some integer?
are your columns are dynamic or you always want sum score1 and score2 ?

Comment: i want create new column = score1 + score2 bro

Comment: As noted by @mehrdad-pedramfar, if the columns are static, you don't need a hybrid *method*, but a *property*. Using a hybrid in a filter is as easy as pie: `session.query(...).filter(Wallet.total_score > 9000)`